# Merge and center multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

How do I merge and center multiple row in Excel?

For example I want to merge and center row A1&A2, B1&B2, C1&C2 .. F1&F2 and A3&A4, B3&B4, C3&C4 .. F3&F4 and etc to A902&903 .. F902..903

Comment: Did you ever try the macro recorder?

Comment: As you can see, a simple google search would have been enough : http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/merge-unmerge-cell-range/ It's a site to help you progress, so we need to see that you tried before coming here to ask. So start from there and edit your question!
Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I agree with the comments to the question and then here we prefer to assist with code which have been developed but is not working correctly and that this is not a please give me this code site.

Adding that Loops are not the easiest thing to learn sometimes, unless you are logically minded.

Having said that, to show the OP how to develop Loops and seeing that the OP is new I provide the answer below.

Comment: @DanielAlder thanks for the suggestion, actually I already ask Mr.Google to make a code but it seems I find a dead end to make the code looping, is just got too many errors that make my brain crashed. My apologize for my manners to directly asking the solution for my errors.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen first of all sir thank you very much for the code, is solved my problem very fast. Again my apologize for my manner in asking question, next time I will add my coding. You got actually correct in guessing my problem, I just got too many errors to make the code looping. Anyway you also correct that I'am new in this programming world. I will try my best to keep up. Again many thanks for the code, you're a nice person sir.

Comment: @Heriyanto is there data in your Cells already? What errors came up? Or did my code work correctly?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen really sorry for the late reply cause I don't see any notification for your reply.

Your code is doing great, I just did a little modification and its a great time saver in doing my job, really helpful, many thanks to you sir..

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim Range1 As Range
    'Looping through the rows steppin up by two each time
    For r = 1 To 902 Step 2

        'Looping through the Columns
        For col = 1 To 6

            'Setting the range for the two cells
            Set Range1 = Range(Cells(r, col), Cells(r + 1, col))
            'Merging the cells
            Range1.Merge
            'Setting horizontal alignment
            Range1.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next col
    Next r

End Sub
```

Please note that the script will merge rows 901 and 902 which follows form merging rows 1 and 2 and stepping up by 2 each time. If you want to merge rows 903 and 904 then change the 902 to 904.

Answer (score -1):

Merge cell A1 with A2 and then auto-fill format for the whole range (time ~5-7 sec)